# Azure Function triggered by EventGrid on Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid

I have followed the [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/resize-images-on-storage-blob-upload-event?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=net) to process event based on blob being created in Azure storage.

The event is firing but the event code to process the image is bypassed as the input stream parameter is not being populated by the EventGrid event. This should be passing through the  path of the blob (image file) to process.

```
 public static async Task Run(
        [EventGridTrigger]EventGridEvent eventGridEvent,
        [Blob("{data.url}", FileAccess.Read)] Stream input,
        ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            log.LogInformation("Entered Thumbnail Function ..");

            if (input != null) 
            { //doesn't get to here ..
```

The log each time the event fires is

```
2018-11-15T05:33:41.096 [Information] Executing 'Thumbnail' (Reason='EventGrid trigger fired at 2018-11-15T05:33:41.0781270+00:00' ..

2018-11-15T05:33:41.096 [Information] Entered Thumbnail Function

2018-11-15T05:33:41.096 [Information] Executed 'Thumbnail' (Succeeded, 

2018-11-15T05:33:41.096 [Information] Executing 'Thumbnail' (Reason='EventGrid trigger fired at 2018-11-15T05:33:41.0781270+00:00', 

2018-11-15T05:33:41.096 [Information] Entered Thumbnail Function

2018-11-15T05:33:41.096 [Information] Executed 'Thumbnail' (Succeeded,
```

Comment: I ran the sample and it is fine for me, the binding works. Which version of az functions/ event grid extensions are using (nuget package version)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tutorial works for [v1 c# script function](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/function-image-upload-resize/blob/v1/imageresizerfunc/run.csx) as you can see it mentions [csx file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/resize-images-on-storage-blob-upload-event?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=net#deploy-the-function-code) when talking about function code. But now the project link points to v2 pre-compiled code, changes in the code could cause problem when we follow the tutorial strictly.

Let's fix the inconsistency with two steps.

1. The key point is function wasn't connected to the blob Storage account created in [part1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-upload-process-images?tabs=net#create-a-storage-account), hence we got null input stream.

   Since we have created an app setting `myblobstorage_STORAGE` in [this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/resize-images-on-storage-blob-upload-event?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=net#configure-the-function-app), we only have to add it in our function code.

   ```
   public static async Task Run(
       [EventGridTrigger]EventGridEvent eventGridEvent,
       [Blob("{data.url}", FileAccess.Read, Connection = "myblobstorage_STORAGE")] Stream input,
       ILogger log)
   ```
2. In the same step, tutorial sets an app setting `myContainerName` for container `thumbnails` created in Blob Storage Account in [part1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-upload-process-images?tabs=net#create-blob-storage-containers).

   But in our code we can see it connects to the [Storage account created for Function app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/resize-images-on-storage-blob-upload-event?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=net#create-an-azure-storage-account)  with `AzureWebJobsStorage` and wants to get container name from app setting `THUMBNAIL_CONTAINER_NAME`.

   The quick fix is to replace `AzureWebJobsStorage` and `THUMBNAIL_CONTAINER_NAME`, and set a constant for `thumbnailWidth`.

   ```
   private static readonly string BLOB_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("myblobstorage_STORAGE");
   ...
   var thumbnailWidth = 100;
   var thumbContainerName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("myContainerName");
   ```

   Of course you could choose to add `THUMBNAIL_WIDTH` in Application settings of Azure portal.

Republish and everything should work.

Comment: how does it know what value to bind to `Blob("{data.url}"`?

Comment: This doesn't work for Azure Functions v1 (with WebJobs packages)...

Comment: @AlexGordon.  I found an answer to the data.url question [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/13024).  Deep in this discussion ramya-rao-a says, "According to [JSON payloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#json-payloads) and [binding expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-trigger?tabs=javascript%2Cbash#event-schema), since the event data payload is a JSON object, you are able to refer to anything inside it in the bindings."

Answer (score 2):

The data will never be passed in. Event Grid event will only pass metadata, which will include blob URI you could use to retrieve the content if you need to.

Comment: Hi Sean, the blob binding is using `{data.url}` metadata from the event grid event  to bind directly to the blob, it supposed to work

Comment: I'd raise an issue with Functions GitHub repo.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the currently accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53314953/816663), you can also make it work without adding the `Connection` parameter if your Function app has a system or user-assigned identity that has the appropriate Blob permissions on the storage account.